# Retreiving results from GraphAPI Post in Javascript

Tags: javascript, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm attempting to create a new team using GraphAPI:

```
let team = {
        "template@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')",
        "displayName": "name",
        "description": "desc"
}
      
let result = await graphClient
        .api('/teams')
        .post(team);
console.log(result);
```

The result comes back as a ReadableStream object, and I can't figure out how to get the id of the object that's been created. Advice and pointers would be greately appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is as follows:

```
let team = {
        "template@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')",
        "displayName": "name",
        "description": "desc"
}
      
let result = await graphClient
        .api('/teams')
        .responseType(MicrosoftGraph.ResponseType.RAW)
        .post(team);
console.log(result.headers.get('client-request-id'));
```